# What does the arrow with 2 lines through it mean?

Tags: keyboard, xcode

In Xcode, a lot of the shortcuts use an arrow with 2 lines though it:

[image]

What is the keystroke corresponding to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the page or scroll up key. On a MacBook, the keystroke is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

---

> “What Do the ⌘, ⇧, ⌥, ⌃, ⎋, ↩, ⇥, ↖ and ↘ Menu Symbols Mean?”

Each symbol corresponds to a key on your keyboard:

⌘ — Command/Apple key

⇧ — Shift key

⌥ — Option/Alt key

⌃ — Control key

↩ — Return key

⇥ — Tab key

⎋ — Escape key

↖ — Home key (Function-Left Arrow on laptops)

↘ — End key (Function-Right Arrow on laptops)

The official macOS User Guide has a handy reference:

- [What are those symbols shown in menus on Mac?](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/cpmh0011/mac)

Comment: Just beat me to it. Daniel Aleksandersen also provides [Unicode symbols for the Mac keyboard special keys](http://my.opera.com/daniel/blog/2012/02/27/unicode-symbols-for-the-mac-keyboard-special-keys)

Comment: Ok, here's one I haven't been able to figure out.. `ClrLn`?

Comment: Clear Line. With Emacs key bindings, Ctrl-k.